# Creating a dynamic bit of text in the middle of a paragraph

Tags: html, css, widget

Essentially what I want to achieve is a a dynamic portion of text - in the middle of a paragraph, that is dynamic. I am having trouble creating an in-line `div` (or `span`) that can contain something like an unordered list or several other `spans` which I can move up or down to show them. Think a window (with overflow) that contains 4 divs stacked on top of each other, with only enough room to show one of them (the rest are hidden). I want to be able to move this stack up and down to show other parts of this stack.

I was hoping someone could reply with a jsfiddle that shows a big block of text with a dynamic portion in the middle of it, in line with the rest of the text in the paragraph.

Comment: Are you talking, like, 4 draggables stacked on top of each other that you can drag away to see what's underneath?

Comment: do you mean an [accordion widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/), or a [stack panel](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwStackPanel)?

Comment: It's a little hard to explain what I want. Think of a sentence. In that sentence, I want one of the words to be replaced with a stack of words - with an opening at the top one so that only the word on top is display (and the others beneath it are hidden). I want jQuery to move this "stack" up and down periodically to show different words. So the sentence stays the same except one word will change.

Comment: Can you just use a `<span>` and use javascript to replace the content of the span every 10 seconds?  What's with the up/down business?

Comment: @Marc Changing the contents of the span would move the text around it. The up/down business is just a transition for looks.

Comment: @JordanScales, I think you might just need to use an `inline-block` CSS.  Have a look at this partially working fiddle to see how the box size stays constant: http://jsfiddle.net/F7uKH/ (there's something funny w/the JS not seeing my function, but you'll get the idea)

Comment: @Marc very cool, however I'm finding that this changes the line height - http://jsfiddle.net/F7uKH/1/. Also, having child elements **inside** of this div is proving difficult.

Comment: @JordanScales, you didn't mention anything about needing child elements in there.  And line height can be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this, using [jQuery Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement).

http://jsfiddle.net/RqHFL/

Apply the "draggable" to you div like this:

```
$( "#draggable1" ).draggable({ axis: "y" }); //constrained to y axis movement
```

Comment: @EliranMalka, I concur.  No part of my answer suggested it was.

Comment: Pretty close to what I want. But I want one stack of items with a small opening that can display one of the items. Then I want jQuery to be able to move the stack up and down periodically to show different items. However, I want this to be in-line of a paragraph without causing strange spacing errors.

Answer (score 0):

After some consideration, `vertical-align: bottom` seemed to be my best friend.